# Feynman-Kac formula: Ito's lemma for exponentiated integrals $e^{-\int b dr}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider the stochastic process
$$
dy = f(y,s)ds + g(y,s)dw
$$
where, $w$ is Brownian motion.
Now consider the following exponentiated integral
$$
z_1(s) = \exp \left[ - \int_t^s b(y(r),r) dr \right]
$$
This object appears in the Feynman-Kac formula and its derivation (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula#Partial_proof) and [page 3 of this lecture notes](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Ekohn/pde.finance/2011/section1.pdf)). The stochastic differential $d z_1$ is simply
$$
dz_1(s) = -z_1 b(y(s),s) ds
$$
i.e. this is effectively ordinary differentiation. I was expecting more terms to appear in the above differential due to Ito's lemma, which would give
$$
dz_1(s) = \left( \partial_s z_1 + f\partial_y z_1 + \frac{g^2}{2}\partial_y^2 z_1 \right) ds + (g \partial_y z_1) dw
$$
and the partial derivatives wrt $y$ would have acted on the integrand $b(y(r),r)$. However, it seems only the $(\partial_s z_1) ds$ term in the RHS above is being retained. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: $z_1(s)$ is a differentiable function of $s$. That's why. It is not a function of $y(s)$ on which any partial derivatives could act.